# Angular App Compiled successfully, getting error my-app did not match any elements, could you guide me what could be wrong?

Tags: angular, typescript

[image]

[image]

routing.module.ts :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'; // CLI imports router
import { BoardComponent } from './board/board.component';
import { ViewlistComponent } from './viewlist/viewlist.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ViewlistComponent },

  { path: 'View-List', component: ViewlistComponent },
]; // sets up routes constant where you define your routes

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class RoutingModule {}
```

app.component.html :

```
<div class="navbar">
  <h1 class="brand">Project Manager / <small>Exemple</small></h1>
  <span>&nbsp;</span>
  <a class="main-btn" routerLink="/View-List" routerLinkActive="active"
    >button2</a
  >
</div>

<div class="interface"></div>

<!-- <app-board [board]=board></app-board>
  <app-info></app-info> -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

As you see I'm trying to load my app, it's compiled successfully, but it's giving error when I load the app in browser. I'm trying to understand what I have done wrong in here. can anyone tell me the reason for this error ?

Comment: Check your `index.html` file. Is `<app-root>` there?

Comment: Could you add your `app.component.ts` to the description ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that index.html is missing `<my-app>` element.
Could you check `index.html` and add below in `<body>`:

```
 <my-app></my-app>
```